# I am getting error using Laravel login API on Live server

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-7

I am getting an error using laravel api, the error only appears when I have uploaded my project on live server, but it is working on live server

```
syntax error, unexpected 'Parser' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)
```

Controller for API:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User; 
// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; 
use Validator;
use Auth;

    class UserController extends Controller
    {
        public $successStatus = 200;
        /** 
         * login api 
         * 
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
         */ 
        public function login(){ 
            if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){ 
                $user = Auth::user(); 
                $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
                return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus); 
            } 
            else{ 
                return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
            } 
        }
    }
```

The error is in this file,

```
ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'Parser' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in file /home/.../.../.../project/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Configuration.php on line 22
```

[image]

Comment: [Package](https://packagist.org/packages/lcobucci/jwt) check package version that compatible with Laravel 7. May be PHP version issue. Confirm PHP version with the package and use compatible package version. May this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by updating php version from 7.3 to 7.4, although in package.json the require version is 7.2.5